# jupyter notebook function recognized data created in above cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Using pandas==1.2.1

MRE:

```
data = "aaaa"
def JoinStr(a):
    return data + a

JoinStr("sd")
```

this outputs "aaaasd"

But from my understanding function doesn't know what `data` is unless it is given it, why is this possible in jupyter notebook? all data assigned in jupyter notebook(or is this for all python) work as global variable?

Comment: yes, they are all global

Comment: @python_user this is not just for jupyter notebook right?

Comment: this is not just for jupyter, you can paste this in a file and get the same behavior, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function explains some of this

Answer (score 0):

In Python (with or without Jupyter) variables are looked for in the local space and, if there's no match, in the global space.

A function like yours can see the global value of `data`, unless you have a local variable of `data` as well.

If your function wants to modify the value of `data`, you need to insert the line
`global data` inside the function

BTW, there's a python convention that function names should only user lower case letters and the underscore. If you name your functions differently, you code will run but confuse other people reading it.